# How to test maven version-ranges?

Tags: build-automation, versioning, dependency-management, maven

What's the best way to test the validity of version-ranges in maven builds? For example, let's say I have a module that depends on slf4j versions [1.5.0,1.7.0). I think that the only way to be confident that the range is correct is to build and test against various versions in that range. Is there a way to get maven to attempt to build the module using the earliest and latest version in the range? How about multiple versions? How about ranges for multiple libraries?

Comment: If you are heading that way, wouldn't you need then to test all possible combinations of library versions.  Otherwise, this idea doesn't make sense.

Comment: I don't think so, but it couldn't hurt.